# Why does stage.stageWidth in flash Builder 4.6 using flex on android not work?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Good afternoon, 
I am creating a android app using adobe air (flex sdk 4.6.0) and i am trying to find out what the width of the phone screen is in pixels. So I am fallowing the tutorial [here](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/09/29/flex-for-mobile-device-form-factor-detection/) but when ever i copy the code into my project and click run it always gives me this error "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." and goes to the line that has stage.stageWidth I have also tried stage.width but it does the same thing. So does stage.stageWidth no longer work or how do you tell the screen size of the tablet or phone? Was it replaced with something else for phones? I am trying to get the information so i can center images in the center of the screen using action script.

```
protected function init():void {
            //function run at creationComplete="init()"
            movePhotoToCenter(myIMG1);
            // trying to get the stage width so that i can center a img that is allready added to the flex code and has a id of "myIMG1"
        }



        protected function movePhotoToCenter(img:Image):void {
            //"error here" where im centering the image
            var centerOfStage:Number = stage.stageWidth/2;
            var Xnumber:Number = centerOfStage - (img.width/2);
            trace(Xnumber);
            var move:Move = new Move(img);
            move.xFrom = img.x;
            move.xTo = Xnumber;
            move.yFrom = img.y;
            move.yTo = img.y;
            move.duration = 3000;
            move.play();
            trace(img.width);
            img.scaleX=1;
            img.scaleY=1;
            trace(img.width);   
        }
```

Thanks for you help,
Justin

Comment: `stage` is only not null when the `DisplayObject` has been added to the stage. Are you sure you are evaluating that in a context when you know its on the stage (usually by waiting for the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event)?

Comment: I'm running it in the creation complete event. init():void { stage.stageHeight; } I need to what till afterwards to get the stage demotions?

Comment: edit your question and add the relevant sections of your class

Comment: Its updated i can also seen the hole thing if needed.

Answer (score 4):

The `creationComplete` complete event fires when it has been added to *a* display list, not necessarily the *Stage's* display list. `creationComplete` fires when that this object and all of its children have been created and added to *something*.

There is another event to bind to called `addedToStage` (in flex land anyway), that will occur when the `DisplayObject` has actually been added to the stage.

Note that `creationComplete` will only fire once after instantiating an object and adding it as a child to something, where `addedToStage` will fire any time that it gets added to the stage (in the case that it gets removed and re-added later without reconstucting the object).

See [this blog post](http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2008/08/22/after-creationcomplete-a-flex-components-stage-property-is-what-null/) for some more details on the subject.